# Trying to read csv file info, and print it as the following

Tags: python, list, csv, indexing

I have to use csv module to import data from this following information.

```
ALPHABETICAL ORDER,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,Positions,,,,Classifications,,,,,,,
Company,Booth,Full-Time,"Full-Time Visa Sponsor",Part-Time,Internship,Freshman,Sophomore,Junior,Senior,Post-Bacs,MS,PhD,Alumni
AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,
Baylor College of Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent
CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent
Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
ExxonMobil,11,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
,...
Flow-Cal Inc.,16,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,All
Global Shop Solutions,18,Yes,,,Yes,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
Harris County CTS,22,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
HCSS,29,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
Hitachi Consulting,13,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,,
HP Inc.,1,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,Recent
INT Inc.,20,Yes,Yes,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,MS,PhD,
JPMorgan Chase & Co,3,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
Leidos,390,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
McKesson,26,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,
MRE Consulting Ltd.,2,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,All
NetIQ,7,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
PROS,21,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,PhD,All
San Jacinto College  ,14,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
SAS,4,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
Smartbridge,8,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
Sogeti USA,15,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
Southwest Research Institute,12,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
The Reynolds and Reynolds Company,23,Yes,Yes,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,All
UH Enterprise Systems,9,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
U.S. Marine Corps,25,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,All
ValuD Consuting LLC,5,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
Wipro,24,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,
BOOTH ORDER,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Booth,Positions,,,,Classifications,,,,,,,
Company,#,Full-Time,"Full-Time
Visa Sponsor",Part-Time,Internship,Freshman,Sophomore,Junior,Senior,Post-Bacs,MS,PhD,Alumni
HP Inc.,1,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,Recent
"MRE Consulting, Ltd.",2,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,All
JPMorgan Chase & Co,3,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
SAS,4,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
ValuD Consuting LLC,5,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
NetIQ,7,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
Smartbridge,8,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
UH Enterprise Systems,9,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,
ExxonMobil,11,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,
Southwest Research Institute,12,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
Hitachi Consulting,13,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,,
San Jacinto College  ,14,,,,Yes,,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
Sogeti USA,15,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,MS,,
"Flow-Cal, Inc.",16,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,All
CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent
Global Shop Solutions,18,Yes,,,Yes,,,,Sr,PB,,,All
Baylor College of Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent
"INT, Inc.",20,Yes,Yes,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,MS,PhD,
PROS,21,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,MS,PhD,All
Harris County CTS,22,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,PhD,All
The Reynolds and Reynolds Company,23,Yes,Yes,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,All
Wipro,24,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,PB,,,
U.S. Marine Corps,25,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,All
McKesson,26,Yes,,,,,,,Sr,,,,
Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
HCSS,29,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,Recent
Leidos,30,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,MS,,
```

So I have to get the information from row 2 and make it print as such

```
0 Company
1 Booth
2 Full-Time
3 Full-Time Visa Sponsor
4 Part-Time
5 Internship
6 Freshman
7 Sophomore
8 Junior
9 Senior
10 Post-Bacs
11 MS
12 PhD
13 Alumni
```

I am not sure how you can make it print line by line, and with the numbers on the left side. This is my code that I've tried doing so far

```
import csv
filename = "Spring.csv"                     #I assigned the file to a variable
f = open(filename)                          #I couldn't leave it default due to UTF-8 error from orginial
reader = csv.reader(f)

output = []


with open( 'Spring.csv', 'r') as t:
    rows = list(reader)
    output.append(rows[2])


print(output)
```

My output right now is the following

```
[['Company', 'Booth', 'Full-Time', 'Full-Time Visa Sponsor', 'Part-Time', 'Internship', 'Freshman', 'Sophomore', 'Junior', 'Senior', 'Post-Bacs', 'MS', 'PhD', 'Alumni']]
```

I **CAN'T** use pandas module for this either. It's for an introductory COSC class. :)

> I also think I am going to have to assign values to that table later
>   with questions.
>
> I don't want to make the question any more confusing, but I think
>   that's referring to indexing it.

Comment: Why are you opening `f = open(filename)` but then also opening `Spring.csv` and **not use it**?

Comment: Yeah the second row has the information needed to make that table though.

Comment: That's the 3rd row, by the way. You don't need to read the whole file to get that info. Just skip the first two rows (`next(reader)` takes one and returns it, so call that twice to skip lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
import csv
filename = "Spring.csv"                     #I assigned the file to a variable
f = open(filename)                          #I couldn't leave it default due to UTF-8 error from orginial
reader = csv.reader(f)

output = []


with open( 'Spring.csv', 'r') as t:
    rows = list(reader)
    for i,v in enumerate(rows[2]):           #---->enumerate
        print(i, v)
```

**[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)**

Comment: Oh wow! That worked. Will this save into my output=[]?  I am so sorry, I am just new and trying to make sense of it all. 

Thanks so much though

Comment: : is missing in for loop for i,v in enumerate(rows[2])  code will not work by simple copy paste.

Comment: Yeah I saw he missed out on the :